# MSP430 communication over USB

Tags: serial-communication, msp430, code-composer

I just started programming an MSP430 2274 with Code Composer, and I'm wondering how to get the computer to output information from the MSP430. (Eventually, I want to send information from one MSP430 to another and have that information displayed on the computer screen)

This feels like it should be so simple, but I can't seem to find an explanation anywhere.

Something like a "hello-world"-ish program that prints to the console "the button was pressed" when the button is pressed would be extremely helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using a LaunchPad?

Comment: No. The box says MSP430 eZ430-RF2500 if that's relevant...

It also says that if it's not relevant.

Comment: That is relevant. I'll post an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you're using the eZ430-RF2500 development kit. This kit can easily be connected to your PC to send serial data to it. To do so, you must write the code to program the USCI to be configured in UART mode.

To do this, please refer to TI documentation: http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau227e/slau227e.pdf

Also, refer to TI software examples: http://www.ti.com/product/MSP430F2274/toolssoftware

Once you've configured the USCI to function in UART mode, you can begin writing a driver to control sending and receiving serial data.

To send and receive from your PC, use a tool like teraterm or hyperterminal. Connect using the correct baud rate, data rate, stop bits, and parity. I believe the eZ430-RF2500 is fixed to 9600, 8 data, no parity, and 1 stop (9600 8-N-1).

Be sure to also download and install any drivers that are needed for that development kit if you haven't already done so.

Comment: Thank you.

As I said, I am very new to this - I don't even know where to begin with your advice. Can you give me some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

You want to send data through PC to MSP430 controller means first you have to implement UART program for MSP430 controllers.

for example Msp430-1 is your transmitter and Mp430-2 is your receiver.
you want to send data through MSP430-1 controller means first you need to implement UART interrupt programs means transmitter and receiver,UART tx & RX examples are available in TI website you can use it.

Now MSP430-1 controller want to send means,As per you requirement you want to use terminals(Real-term,tera-term) in your PC, using terminals you can able to send data to MSP430-1 controller, this controller receive data via UART RX, after receiving total packet send data to MSP430-2 controller using UART.

concentrate: After download UART programs, conforms that programs are implemented with which BAUD-RATE(ex:9600 or 4800 or 115200) and also check terminal UART settings means BAUD-RATE,PARTY bits [use this link](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/terminal-basics/tera-term-windows) for better understand how to set terminal settings for UART.

Answer (score 0):

I came accross this question while searching for msp430, I've written a short serial output program for msp430g2et launchpad in code composer studio that outputs the given character array to the serial output in 19200 baud, you can check the code:
https://github.com/selimg76/microcontroller/blob/master/msp430serialmonitor

and there's a detailed explanation video here:
https://youtu.be/Fzf8q6fgxfQ